# Filter two arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following set of arrays,

```
var records = [{ 'id': 'ee31ee6a-7f95-49fb-a02f-2a9ef36c2f8b', 
'name': 'Test', 'type': 'user' },
{ 'id': 'ee31ee6a-7f95-49fb-a02f-2a9ef36c2f8b', 
'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770', 'type': 'register' },
{ 'id': 'ee31ee6a-7f95-49fb-a02f-2a9ef36c2f8b', 
'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd772', 'type': 'register' },
];

var registration = [
{ 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770', 'id': '123', 'index': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770'}, 
{ 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd772', 'id': '456', 'index': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770'}, 
{ 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd771', 'id': '789' 'index': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd776'}];
```

and want the following output

```
result = [
{ 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770', 'id': '123'}, 
{ 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd772', 'id': '456'}]
```

I basically want the registration array filtered based on the name property in the records arrays as I need the id values from the registration array.

Is there a combination of methods from the lodash library that I could use to get the desired output?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: In your example result array, the objects have lost the `index` property. This indicates that you want to both filter the array and mutate the values. Is this correct?

Comment: @tebs1200 Yes it is correct. But I'd request you and everyone else to **let OP share effort**.

Comment: Are you trying to: "Find records in registration array where record name exists in  records array"? Do the two arrays have many-to-many relationship?

Comment: I tried using a combination of _.flatten and _.filter from the Lodash library but this didn't work in this case as registration array contained two properties with the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
result = _.filter(registration, x => _.some(records, {name: x.name}))
```

Comment: Though this is the correct answer, I would like to request to delete for now. Please let OP to share efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`_.intersectionBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#intersectionBy).

```js
var records = [{ 'id': 'ee31ee6a-7f95-49fb-a02f-2a9ef36c2f8b', 'name': 'Test', 'type': 'user' }, { 'id': 'ee31ee6a-7f95-49fb-a02f-2a9ef36c2f8b', 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770', 'type': 'register' }, { 'id': 'ee31ee6a-7f95-49fb-a02f-2a9ef36c2f8b', 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd772', 'type': 'register' }],
    registration = [{ 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770', 'id': '123', 'index': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770'}, { 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd772', 'id': '456', 'index': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd770'}, { 'name': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd771', 'id': '789', 'index': '9300731e-3c97-4719-8dc2-fcf0a29fd776'}],
    result = _.intersectionBy(registration, records, "name");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```